# My Content from API is not being shown in Flutter

Tags: api, flutter, dart

I wrote my code in flutter, and used NewsAPI.org for getting content about news, such as heading, image, content etc. I made a class "News" and `ArticleModel()` for retrieving and using the information. I used Conditional Operator (? :) for checking if the data is received, then show it, else `CircularProgressIndiactor()` is shown. After running the app, `CircularProgressIndiactor()` shows up and no information is shown/loaded. Can anyone help me here??

No error or warning is shown, and code compiles successfully, but no information is shown up.

Here is the main file, home.dart -

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:news_app/helper/data.dart';
import 'package:news_app/helper/news.dart';
import 'package:news_app/models/article_model.dart';
import 'package:news_app/models/category_models.dart';

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  List<CategoryModel> categories = new List<CategoryModel>();
  List<ArticleModel> articles = new List<ArticleModel>();
  bool loading = true;

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    categories = getCategories();
    getNews();
  }

  getNews() async {
    News newsClass = News();
    await newsClass.getNews();
    articles = newsClass.news;
    setState(() {
      loading = false;
      print('Done');
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Text(
                'Flutter',
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.black,
                ),
              ),
              Text(
                'News',
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.blue,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          //elevation: 2.0,
        ),
        body: loading
            ? Center(
                child: Container(
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                ),
              )
            : SingleChildScrollView(
                child: Container(
                  child: Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      ///Categories
                      Container(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0),
                        height: 70.0,
                        child: ListView.builder(
                          itemCount: categories.length,
                          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                          shrinkWrap: true,
                          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                            return CategoryTile(
                              imageUrl: categories[index].imageUrl,
                              categoryName: categories[index].categoryName,
                            );
                          },
                        ),
                      ),

                      ///Blogs
                      Container(
                        child: ListView.builder(
                          shrinkWrap: true,
                          itemCount: articles.length,
                          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                            return BlogTile(
                              imageUrl: articles[index].urlToImage,
                              title: articles[index].title,
                              desc: articles[index].description,
                            );
                          },
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class CategoryTile extends StatelessWidget {
  final imageUrl, categoryName;
  CategoryTile({this.imageUrl, this.categoryName});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {},
      child: Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 16.0),
        child: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            ClipRRect(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6.0),
              child: Image.network(
                imageUrl,
                width: 120.0,
                height: 160.0,
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              width: 120.0,
              height: 60.0,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.black26,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6.0)),
              child: Text(
                categoryName,
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                  fontSize: 14.0,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class BlogTile extends StatelessWidget {
  final String imageUrl, title, desc;
  BlogTile(
      {@required this.imageUrl, @required this.desc, @required this.title});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Image.network(imageUrl),
          Text(title),
          Text(desc),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Here is the News.dart file -

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:news_app/models/article_model.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class News {
  List<ArticleModel> news = [];

  Future<void> getNews() async{
    String url="http://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=in&category=business&apiKey=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";

    var response = await http.get(url);

    var jsonData = jsonDecode(response.body);

    if(jsonData["status"] == "ok") {
      jsonData["articles"].forEach((element){
        if(element['urlToImage'] != null && element['description'] != null) {
          ArticleModel articleModel = ArticleModel(
            title: element['title'],
            author: element['author'],
            description: element['description'],
            url: element['url'],
            urlToImage: element['urlToImage'],
            content: element['content'],
          );
          news.add(articleModel);
        }
      });
    }
  }
}
```

And at last, ArticleModel.dart -

```
class ArticleModel {
  String author, title, description;
  String url, urlToImage;
  String content;

  ArticleModel({this.title, this.description, this.author, this.content, this.url, this.urlToImage});
}
```

Comment: I have a project for NewsAPI by using GetX, if you are interested the source code is [here](https://github.com/warcayac/NewsApiFlutterWithGetX).

Comment: Ουιλιαμ Αρκευα Thanks a lot man

Answer (score 0):

Updating your request URL from `http` to `https` will give you expected result.

Update URL to: `"https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=in&category=business&apiKey="`

**Note:** Don't share your API key in any open platforms for security reasons.